# How to pause or re run directive when that tab is focused?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-include

I have an html page and I have created 3 separate tabs using **Bootstrap** each having their own partials, imported using ng-include. Here is the code for the view -

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="dashboard-tabs">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#opportunity" aria-controls="opportunity" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Opportunity</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#effort" aria-controls="effort" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Effort</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#results" aria-controls="results" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Results</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<!--    Page content    -->
<div class="tab-content">


<!--            Opportunity Tab-->
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="opportunity" class="container" >
        <div ng-include="'partials/opportunityView.html'"></div>
    </div>




<!--            Efforts Tab-->
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="effort" >
        <div ng-include="'partials/effortView.html'"></div>
    </div>


<!--            Results Tab-->
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="results">
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, Opportunity view is the default focus view and it runs just fine. I have a directive inside the partial/template for **Efforts** tab (second tab), and inside that directive link's function I am using jquery to compute the width of a table row in directive's template. But on page load, it shows the width as 0. I think it may be because Efforts view is hidden on page load.
So, how can I solve this problem? Can I re compile directive code on Effort's page load or can I pause it's execution untill Efforts tab is on focus?

Comment: first of all I dont like using ng-include... I would rather use a directive that runs the html its much more coherent. secondly you can add a directive to that code that catches the focus event and $compiles the html.

Comment: @Jony-Y Can you tell me in a little detail how to do that?

Comment: sure, what do you need? a directive that catches the focus event?

Comment: @Jony-Y Yes that will be cool. Also I will be using this directive in many places, so I am hoping of a solution that is built inside directive and does not depend on some outer setting

Comment: ok, so what exactly do you need? a directive that does what? re-renders the code on focus?, I kinda need more info

Comment: @Jony-Y Yes, either a directive that does not renders till it gains focus or that re-renders the code on focus. From re rendering I mean compiling the template and running the link function again

Comment: @Jony-Y Are you working on it?

Comment: sorry dude... completely forgot about you there... Im at work Ill try to help out in a bit